# Fiddling with locale so that weeks start on Monday

Tags: date, locale

I use the `C.UTF-8` locale and all is well, I'm pretty happy with it but weeks starting on Sunday...
Is there a single or combination locale setting that changes only the first day of the week, leaving the names of days and months in English?

I simply want that `locale first_weekday` to return `2`. No particular concern for any application. `locale`, as far as I know, is regulated by POSIX (I'd be happy to be corrected) so, at least for now, I don't see a particular motivation for detailing my system any more.

EDIT

Following [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544743/fiddling-with-locale-so-that-weeks-start-on-monday?noredirect=1#comment1010667_544743) from [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) I'd like to inform you that I'm using Debian Sid.

Comment: From a very quick-and-dirty standpoint, both `LC_TIME=en_GB` and `LC_TIME=en_DK` have first_weekday 2, but may also use different date formatting.

Comment: Thank you @UlrichSchwarz, `LC_TIME=en_DK locale first_weekday` returns `1` and raises an error `locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory` (notably `LC_TIME=en_DK date` seems OK and with `en_EN` I see the same behaviors)

Comment: I'm unsure `LC_TIME` is the way to go, e.g., `LC_TIME=it_IT date` ⇒ `Wed Oct  2 12:55:19 CEST 2019`

Comment: But do you want to keep the other US-specific time settings of the C.UTF-8 locale,  like the middle-endian `d_fmt="%m/%d/%y"`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the itch that I really need to scratch is `first_weekday` ... for the rest I'm rather agnostic.

Comment: The localisation API is specified by POSIX, but  the locale data is not except for the POSIX/C locale. POSIX doesn't specify the C.UTF-8 locale. There is a lot of variation in locale names across systems, and even when systems happen to agree on the name of a locale (like `en_US.UTF-8` found on many systems), there is a lot of variation on the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three options:

1. create a new locale from C.UTF-8 and just change that first_weekday value. Let's call it X.UTF-8. In Debian, this should do it, if you have permissions on those directories:

```
    cp -R /usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8 /usr/lib/locale/X.UTF-8
    cat /usr/share/i18n/locales/C | sed -E 's/first_weekday[[:blank:]]+1/first_weekday 2/g' | localedef --add-to-archive /usr/lib/locale/X.UTF-8 -i -
    LC_TIME=X.UTF-8 locale first_weekday
```

So you copy the existing definition, just a lazy way to recreate the folder structure, then from the original C.UTF-8 (the name is just "C") you change the line that refers to the first weekday (it could be shorter, with a positional parameter, but I find it's more readable like this).

2. modify that value in your existing C.UTF-8 locale:

```
    cat /usr/share/i18n/locales/C | sed -E 's/first_weekday[[:blank:]]+1/first_weekday 2/g' | localedef --add-to-archive /usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8 -i -
    LC_TIME=C.UTF-8 locale first_weekday
```

3. Well, if you are ok with the other differences between en_GB and C.UTF-8, then these steps should do the change:

Depending on your system, not all locales are available right away. So first, make sure you have en_GB.UTF-8 available (or you will get the error "Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale"):

```
locale -a
```

if you don't, then add it. Since there is no info on your system I cannot tell you how to do it. In Debian/Ubuntu you can do `dpkg-reconfigure locales` (or edit `/etc/locale.gen` to add the locale or, most likely, just uncomment it, and then run `locale-gen`).

Once en_GB.UTF-8 is in the list of available locales, you can then set:

LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8

```
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 locale first_weekday
```

should return 2

This [Debian document](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale) has more info on how to make the change permanent for different environments.

Comment: It seems to me that the locale specification on Debian should be `LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8` (or, anyway, it must reference the character set) — also the last line of your answer says `1` instead of `2`.  Would you mind to correct your answer?

Comment: @gboffi I edited the answer. The character set is optional (I actually tested that before). At least in Debian, many entries are just language_REGION and the character defaults to UTF-8. For example en_IN, csb_PL,... . For others (most of the en_REGION) the character set defaults to ISO-8859-1.  The locale specification does not mandate a character set, but since it does make the answer more complete, I changed it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: `first_weekday` is not the only thing that it changes. See `diff <(LC_TIME=C.UTF-8 locale -k LC_TIME) <(LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 locale -k LC_TIME)`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas is right. So I added a way to really keep everything from C.UTF-8 except the first day of the week.